# Local HuggingFace dataset of images and segmentation is crashed when try to load data

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I'm trying to use Huggingface for the first time.

I don't find any tutorial using segFormer on HuggingFace using local dataset.

I fail when trying to use my local dataset.

I want to fine tune segFormer with my own segmentation data.
I create dataset like this (both image and label are png images)

```
def create_dataset(image_paths, label_paths):
    dataset = datasets.Dataset.from_dict({"image": sorted(image_paths),
                                          "label": sorted(label_paths)})
    dataset = dataset.cast_column("image", datasets.Image())
    dataset = dataset.cast_column("label", datasets.Image())
    return dataset
```

I load pretrained model:

```
model = SegformerForSemanticSegmentation.from_pretrained("nvidia/segformer-b0-finetuned-ade-512-512")
```

Create TrainingArguments, Trainer obj and call "train" :

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer")
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=validation_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
trainer.train()
```

When I call "train" I get "TypeError: must be real number, not PngImageFile inside data_collector.py"
Full error message

> 0%|          | 0/93 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\itishel\PycharmProjects\huggingSegFormer\lib\site-packages\accelerate\data_loader.py", line 384, in **iter**
> current_batch = next(dataloader_iter)
> File "C:\Users\itishel\PycharmProjects\huggingSegFormer\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 681, in **next**
> data = self._next_data()
> File "C:\Users\itishel\PycharmProjects\huggingSegFormer\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 721, in _next_data
> data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
> File "C:\Users\itishel\PycharmProjects\huggingSegFormer\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data_utils\fetch.py", line 52, in fetch
> return self.collate_fn(data)
> File "C:\Users\itishel\PycharmProjects\huggingSegFormer\lib\site-packages\transformers\data\data_collator.py", line 70, in default_data_collator
> return torch_default_data_collator(features)
> File "C:\Users\itishel\PycharmProjects\huggingSegFormer\lib\site-packages\transformers\data\data_collator.py", line 119, in torch_default_data_collator
> batch["labels"] = torch.tensor([f["label"] for f in features], dtype=dtype)
> TypeError: must be real number, not PngImageFile

It crashes inside data_collector.py in "torch_default_data_collector".
Here:

```
    if "label" in first and first["label"] is not None:
        label = first["label"].item() if isinstance(first["label"], torch.Tensor) else first["label"]
        dtype = torch.long if isinstance(label, int) else torch.float
        batch["labels"] = torch.tensor([f["label"] for f in features], dtype=dtype)
```